# grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub2

I am attempting to get GRUB to boot Windows, but I ran into a problem. Whenever I try to run `grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /mnt/bootmgr`, I get this:

```
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda1.
grub-probe: error: disk `hostdisk//dev/sda1' not found.
```

`/dev/sda1` absolutely exists. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The error messages are misleading. The disk exists, you just don't have access to them. Try running that command with `sudo`.